# Creating an Outlook add-in that can read and modify items in a mailbox

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Problem summary: I need to create an Outlook 365 add-in that can change visual properties of items in a mailbox.

I've created a plugin using Yeoman Generator using the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator

This works fine, but the add-in only seems to be enabled for opened email items.

In the following image you can see the generated add-in is disabled, but the Viva Insights add-in is enabled:

[image]

Is what I am trying to do possible with the Yeoman generator? How? If not, can it be done with a VSTO add-in? Is there any place that has example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the ExtensionPoint element in the XML manifest. It defines where an add-in exposes functionality in the Office UI. The documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/extensionpoint?view=powerpoint-js-preview